# Django Admin "Export selected" button not showing in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I'm trying to enable the "Export selected" button in the Django admin for users to download data as an Excel sheet. I'm using django-import-export but the button isn't appearing.

***Here's what I've done:***
Installed django-import-export (pip install django-import-export).

**Trial 1:**

```
class UserAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email'....)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, ImportExportModelAdmin)
```

**Trial 2:**

```
class UserAdmin(ExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email'.....)
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Restarted the development server.

the django-import-export is in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Expected behavior:
The "Export selected" button should appear in the Django admin user list view.

Actual behavior:
The button is not displayed.

**My Question**: Why the button is not showing and how can I fix it.

Any suggestions or insights into why the button might not be showing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Docs for enabling export are [here](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.7/advanced_usage.html#admin-integration).  Try with the [example app](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.7/installation.html#example-app) for reference.  If still not working, it could be a clash with other plugins you may have.

Comment: @toyotaSupra I am not sure what you mean it should appear in the Django Admin

Comment: You can ignore the comment from toyota Supra - it is not relevant to django-import-export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I enabled using the [example app](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.0-rc.1/installation.html#example-app).

1. Use [django-import-export v4](https://pypi.org/project/django-import-export/4.0.0rc1/).
2. Go to the 'Category' model instance and add some new categories.
3. You can now select and export:

[image]

To enable this, simply subclass `ExportActionModelAdmin` (refer to [example code](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/6ce49212747e5bf8118c11d7e4880229444e19e1/tests/core/admin.py#L40)):

```py
class CategoryAdmin(ExportActionModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```